# How can I prevent the width of a plotly legend from restricting the space available for chart data?

Tags: legend, plotly.js

I have a plotly chart in my app.  I have a horizontal legend above the plot area.  When the strings are localized for another language, the width of the legend changes, naturally, but also the plot itself is narrowed, as if to make space for the additional legend text.

The legend is above the plot, so should not interfere with any plot elements.  Is there some setting which will protect the plot dimensions from changes to the legend?

Here is my layout:

```js
{
    legend: {
      x: .5,
      y: 1.3,
      orientation: "h",
      traceorder: "normal",
      bordercolor: '#FFFFFF',
    },
    margin: {
        l: 80,
        r: 40,
        t: 60,
        b: 40
    },
    shapes: [
        {
            name: "4 hour threshold",
            type: "line",
            xref: "paper",
            yref: "y",
            x0: 0,
            y0: 4,
            x1: 1,
            y1: 4,
            line: {
                color: gray,
                width: 1,
                dash: "dot"
            }
        }
    ],
    title: {
        text: "<b>$therapy_report_usage_hours</b>",
        font: {
            family: "Helvetica"
        },
        x: 0.05,
    },
    xaxis: {
        tick0: 6, // start on the 6th tick
        dtick: 7, // label every 7 ticks
        range: [-1, 30]
    },
    yaxis: {
        showline: true,
        ticklen: 10,
        range: [0, 12],
        dtick: 2
    }
}
```

[image: English-language chart]

[image: French-language chart]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to anchor the legend on the right.  Here's the updated legend element from the layout:

```json
{
    x: 1,
    xanchor: "right",
    y: 1.3,
    orientation: "h",
    traceorder: "normal",
    bordercolor: '#FFFFFF',
}
```